# Why does this add 2 pickups to my inventory when I use it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code. I think it is this script.
I have no idea where the error is, but I think it is in `OnTriggerEnter2d` in the second `if` statement.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pickup : MonoBehaviour
{
    private InventoryTest inventory;
    public GameObject itembutton;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        inventory = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<InventoryTest>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < inventory.slots.Length; i++) {
                if (inventory.isfull[i] == false) {
                    inventory.isfull[i] = true;
                    Instantiate(itembutton, inventory.slots[i].transform, false);
                    Destroy(gameObject);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't accidentally have two instances of a script or a collider on your objects do you?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019